# How to push text on forge viewer?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I want put level information on the viewer like the following picture
[image]
Are there any function?
How can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try out this extension:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/placing-custom-markup-dbid

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically add markups to specified coordinates with:

```
markupExt.enterEditMode();
const textMarkup = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.CreateText(ext,"233",{x:90,y:84},{x:88,y:10},"test",{"font-size": 5.8730152675142335, "stroke-color": "#ff0000", "stroke-opacity": 1});
textMarkup.execute()
```